# Right way for setting categories

Tags: categories, menus, filters

My site follows this hierarchy

HTML5 +

- Themes
- Resources
- Books
- Tools

Wordpress +

- Plugins
- Themes
- Tools
- Books

jQuery +

- Plugins
- Tools
- books

and the same combinations for CSS3, SEO and others, but I don't know how to structure the categories and sub-categories in right way and how to target the specific blog-post with url like we select post with a specific category

```
www.example.com/categories
```

How do we target tools(sub-categories) in plugin(category)?

For example

```
www.example.com/categories/sub-category
```

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the settings->permalinks
- Select custom options
- Write /%category%/%postname%
- Use WP No Category Base plugin

Comment: how can i add sub category with category in url 
and the main thing is how to set up categories is that the wight way which i posted above